# OWIN + Global.Asax - Context is dying

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, nlog

I'm trying to work with WebApi + OWIN + SimpleInjector, but somehow, after each request, the whole thing seems to be restarting. For each request, the breakpoing in Global.Asasx is getting hit, and then all the OWIN Startup is executed again to reach app.use(...).

I've found no exception, I've removed all the references to GlobalConfiguration, and the only HttpConfiguration I'm using is the one I've created in Startup.cs on Owin's method: Configure.

Can someone help me with this issue? Debugging took me nowhere :(
My Global.asax has an empty Application_start (just a breakpoint), the the code for Startup.cs is the following:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
SimpleInjectorConfig.Initialize(config);
this.ConfigureAuth(app, SimpleInjectorConfig.container);

WebApiConfig.Register(config);
app.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, Container container)
    {
          // Enables COORS
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            using (var scope = container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
            {
    await next();
});

app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
PublicClientId = "self";
...Code to create OAuthOptions
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

EDIT

I found out what is causing it, but could not solve. NLog does not play along with OWIN, when I disable it, the issue is gone. No exceptions thrown, but the context is always "recycled". The issue seems to be the way Nlog gets it's logger using reflection.